# Removing Admob permissions from AndroidManifest

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

A unity admob plugin is asking for read_phone_state, access_location and external_storage permissions. What is the right way to remove these?

Do I simply delete these lines from the manifest? Or do I have to add tools:node="remove" after each line?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to understand why these permissions are required by the plugin. 
If they are of no use, simply remove those line from the manifest file.

Comment: The official admob plugin for unity does not ask for any of these permissions. I deleted read_phone_state and the dummy ads are showing up.

Comment: Did you check it on the real smartphone?

Comment: Yes. I checked it on my test device. My game is far from complete so it will be some time before I will be able to see some real ads.